# How to find all duplicates in a column and then implement a 'history column' of all the information from duplicates?

Tags: excel, vba

In Column A of Sheet 1, I have a list of serial numbers which contain duplicates. I want to delete all duplicates and instead come up with a history column which captures all the information of the adjacent cells with regards to that serial number.

The logic of my script goes like this:

1. Filter all distinct serial numbers into a new sheet
2. For each cell in new sheet, find all matching cells in sheet 1
3. If they match then copy adjacent columns information and create an new column with new matching information
4. The more serial duplicates are, the bigger the "history" cell of that serial number is going to have

Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I already know how to sort out the unique serial numbers. I am having trouble with my For Loop and comparing the sheet containing duplicates and implementing continuously added information into a cell

```
Dim strStatus As String
Dim strComments As String
Dim strDate As String
Dim strHistory As String

Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Sheet2.Range("A1"), Unique:=True


Sub SortSerialNumbers()    
    Dim I, Atotal As Integer
    Dim found As Range

    Atotal = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 1 To Atotal
        UniqueValue = Worksheets(2).Range("A" & I).Value
        Set found = Sheets(1).Columns("A:A").Find(what:=UniqueValue)

        If found Then
            strStatus = Worksheets(1).Range("B" & I).Value
            strComments = Worksheets(1).Range("C" & I).Value
            strDate = Worksheets(1).Range("D" & I).Value
            strHistory = "strStats | " & "strDate | " & "strComments" & vbCrLf
            Worksheets(2).Rnage("B" & I).Value = strHistory
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

I just need guidance on my syntax because I have the logic down but I don't know how to translate what I want to do with what VBA understands.

Comment: I don't think the logic that is in your code will result in your desired outcome. `.Find` will only return the first cell you find, and then you are simply concatenating the B-D columns into B. You don't aggregate the other occurances of that same value into that string. You want to make use of `.Findnext` and pull together those strings as well.

Comment: So how do I go from here? Use .Findnext and then I will get the desired outcome? I am kinda new to VBA, but I'm trying my best

Comment: You should assign the value only to the cell upon completing your loop. So after `Next I` and in the meanwhile keep expanding it on every match you find.

Comment: So I put `Set FindPN = FindPN.FindNext` after defining `strHistory` and placing the value of `strHistory` after `Next I`. The problem that I have now is that `UniqueValue` is not defined apparently

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677854/excel-findnext-function